# Empty response for data studio assets search API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, looker-studio, service-accounts

I am trying to fetch the data studio assets to manage the permissions based on that data through [APIs](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api).
I am using oAuth2 access token generated using the service account as I want to automate this process and not rely on user consent for authorization every time. [oAuth2 authorization using service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

**Steps I have followed:**

- Created service account in Google cloud and enabled Google Workspace Domain-wide Delegation
- Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account through Google Workspace account
  For the following scopes:

  1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio
  2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
  3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
  4. openid
- Created and signed JWT
- Used JWT token to get the oAuth2 access token to make Datastudio API calls.

**Using the following snippet to generate the signed JWT.**

```py
import jwt
import time
import json
import requests

iat = int(time.time())
exp = iat + 3600

claim_set = {"iss": "datastudio-manager@data-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
             "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
             "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "exp": exp, "iat": iat}

encoded = jwt.encode(claim_set, private_key, algorithm="RS256")

response = requests.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", params={
    "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "assertion": encoded
})

print(response.json()["access_token"])
```

Using token generated from above step to make API call.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets:search?assetTypes=report
```

Response of the above request is `{}` with status 200 and when I am trying to view permissions for a particular asset it is giving me the following response.

API endpoint: https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets/<asset_id>/permissions

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Is authentication using access token generated through the above oAuth2 method supported for Data studio APIs?

Any leads are much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding `sub` to the claim_set?  You have to impersonate a person that has access to that asset. See this [example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest)

Comment: Thanks a lot @NikkoJ! Somehow I thought this is an optional parameter and after adding then it worked like a charm.